# "Cut off a slice of cake", "cut out a slice of cake" or "cut a slice of cake"?

Tags: word-choice

Which one do I say when I want someone to remove one slice of cake like that [image]

Do I cut it out or cut off or just cut? For example:

> Could **cut**/**cut out**/**cut off** one slice of cake for me?

Anyway, is that something a native English speaker would sat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that context, we would say *cut a slice*.

The other phrases exist, but have different uses: neither of them for food, as far as I can think.

*Cut off* means usually means to cut a piece from the end of something long, usually because the piece is wanted for something.

*Cut out* means to cut a bad, or rotten, or diseased, portion of something and leave the rest.